# I want to save all the checkbox values I select

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I m trying to store checkbox value subject_id but when i store this value to database it just store the last selected checkbox inside the database... please help me to sort out the code so I can get all selected values.

I want to save all the checkbox values I selected,but if I check more then one checkbox it always save the last checkbox.

```
 function get_class_section($day='',$section='',$class='')
{

    print_r($section);
    $sections = $this->db->get_where('class_routine' , array(
        'day' => $day,'section_id'=>$section,'class_id'=>$class
    ))->result_array();


    foreach ($sections as $row) {


    echo "<table class=\"table table-bordered datatable\" id=\"table_export\"  >";

    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<th>Subject</th><th colspan=\"2\">status</th>";
    echo "</thead>";

    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>". $this->crud_model->get_subject_name_by_id($row['subject_id'],"<input type=\"text\"  name=\"subject_id\" value=\"subject_id\" >");
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"types[]\"  value=\"".$row['subject_id']."\" set_checkbox('types[]', 'subject_id')>";

      echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>present&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=\"checkbox\"  value=\"1\" ></td>"
      . "<td>Absent&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"types[]\" value=\"0\"></td>";



    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";

    echo "</table>"; 




    }

}
```

how to save all the check-boxes that i selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **foreach  loop** to get all checked checkboxes

Try This:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['types']) && $_REQUEST['types']!=array())
{
  foreach ($_REQUEST['types'] as $key => $value) {

   // in $value,you will get checkbox value

  }
}
```

Comment: where should i put this above the table?

Comment: but when i try to submit values in to the database it retunr an error Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

You should use hidden element for all checkbox

Try this

```
 . "<td>Absent&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"types[]\" value=\"0\"></td>
 <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"types[]\" value=\"0\"> ";
```

Comment: I think that @Yasin Patel answer is coreect